No Sound when Speakers Connected to Line Out
Yesterday at home I was watching some Youtube video when suddenly my speakers stopped working,
I don't know why or how, but they just stopped. I promptly tried switching from the line out port at the back panel to the headphone port at the front and my speakers were working fine.
I have a dell vostro small desktop 3710, I also went through dell support assist hardware diagnosis tool and all hardware was tested to be in working conditions and when I tried searching on the web for solutions, none of the ones I tested worked.
I tried restarting pulseaudio, tried disabling auto-mute from alsamixer, tried messing with pulseaudio daemon.conf file and more.
Strange thing is, when I start/restart my computer, at the login screen and just after that, my speakers work normally, but as soon as I open any application the sound completely disappears and never returns.
Any help is appreciated.

What does messing with and more mean? Any answer is only as good as the info in the question.

silly question but did you check 2 things in particular 1 - that the speaker icon in YT is indeed on and the sound up to max and 2 - in Settings > Sound > Output the correct Output Device is selected and also click on Test button to test the line output as well as System Volume being set (which can also be checked from the systray icon)

@graham - More silly things to check (it's got me several times) - are they still connected and do the speakers have power?  (things do come unplugged)

I believe that the speaker icon does indeed display, can't check it right now because i'm at work, thought from my testing any aplication has no sound, i tested playing some games aswell and no sound was playing, my speakers are indeed fully connected and powered. Connecting it to the headphone port works normally, is just the line out port that doesn't work.
